# How come "with" results in multiple queries in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

From here: https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-eager-loading

Running this line: `App\Post::with('author.profile')->get();` results in 3 queries being executed:

```
[2017-08-04 07:27:27] local.INFO: select * from `posts`  
[2017-08-04 07:27:27] local.INFO: select * from `authors` where `authors`.`id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [1,2,3,4,5] 
[2017-08-04 07:27:27] local.INFO: select * from `profiles` where `profiles`.`author_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How come?
Is there clean way to do this in one query?

I would expect the resulting query to look something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts, authors, profiles 
WHERE posts.author_id = author.id
AND author.profile_id = profiles.id
```

Comment: A big downside of your suggested query: Columns with the same name override each other. In your case, the result would have a single `id` column and its value would come from `profiles` (the last table).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent executes the queries like that so it can hydrate a separate model for each row of data. This is important for enabling other Eloquent features once the models are loaded. With eager loading the number queries are always predictable. `App\Post::with('author.profile')->get();` will always execute three queries, regardless of the number of posts, authors, or profiles. Without eager loading it will run exponentially more queries depending on the number of records returned. This is a result of Eloquent implementing the [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) design pattern.

The example of the "cleaner" way of querying the data is essentially doing a join. You can use a join to get all the data for the various relations in one query. The disadvantage of that in the context of Laravel is all the data will exist in the `Post` model, even though it's sourced from three different tables. This is great if you just want to quickly display all the data, but it becomes more difficult when trying to manipulate and update the data.

This is more a question about using Active Record, and less specific to Eloquent itself. There are lots of arguments for and against the use of active record, that I won't get into. For more information I would recommend you do some reading on Active Record (used by Eloquent), Data Mapper (used by Doctrine), or more generally ORM Design Patterns.

Answer (score 2):

It is still much better than lazy loading, meaning having each query separately.

Your expectation will not work the way you think. You can use join instead.

Something like this:

```
\DB::table('posts as p')
    ->join('authors as a', 'p.author_id', '=', 'a.id')
    ->join('profiles as pr', 'pr.id', '=', 'a.profile_id')
    ->get();
```